# ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException and RollbackException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with hibernate and jpa.

I have a method that is called regularly to retrieve data from a table in database and to send it to another server.

Here is the code of the method :

```
protected List<MessagingMessage> getNewMessages() throws NoMessageAvailableException {
    return messagingPublisher.getNewMessages(application);
}
```

Here is the code from the publisher :

```
@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.class})
public List<MessagingMessage> getNewMessages(String application) throws NoMessageAvailableException {
    List<GpsDataToSend> allGpsDatas = gpsDataToSendService.findByapplicationIgnoreCase(application);
    List<MessagingMessage> allMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (GpsDataToSend gpsDataToSend : allGpsDatas) {
        MessagingMessage message = convertToMessagingMessage(gpsDataToSend);
        // Ajout dans les messages à envoyer au TMS
        allMessages.add(message);
        try {
            // Suppression des données de la base
            gpsDataToSendService.deleteGpsDataToSend(gpsDataToSend.getId());
        } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException oolfa) {
            // Si l'exception est levée, c'est que la donnée a été supprimée, donc déjà été envoyée au TMS
            allMessages.remove(message);
            Long idGpsDataToSend = ((GpsDataToSend) message.getObject()).getId();
            log.info("The GPS message was already sent because the data doesn't exists anymore in database (id : {})", idGpsDataToSend);
        }
    }
    return allMessages;
}
```

The publisher retrieves the data, convert it in a message, and the data is deleted from the database, to be sure that it is only send once.

The problem is that I have 2 servers in loadbalancing, executing the same code, so potentially the 2 servers are retrieving the same data at the same time. Sometimes, on the delete, I had an ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException that occured, telling me that there was no data to delete.
I just handled this Exception to make sure it didn't mess with the rest of the execution.

But now, when an ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException occurs, at the next execution of :

```
protected List<MessagingMessage> getNewMessages() throws NoMessageAvailableException {
    return messagingPublisher.getNewMessages(application);
}
```

I get this exception :

```
2018-04-24 15:58:09 ERROR [pool-3-thread-1] c.g.m.m.w.WepSphereMqQueuePusher [WepSphereMqQueuePusher.java:76] Error getting new message to send org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.getNewMessages(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.geodisbm.mobility.messaging.websphere.WepSphereMqQueuePusher.getNewMessages(WepSphereMqQueuePusher.java:101) [messaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.geodisbm.mobility.messaging.websphere.WepSphereMqQueuePusher.sendAllMessages(WepSphereMqQueuePusher.java:71) [messaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.geodisbm.mobility.messaging.websphere.WepSphereMqQueuePusher.access$000(WepSphereMqQueuePusher.java:16) [messaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.geodisbm.mobility.messaging.websphere.WepSphereMqQueuePusher$1.run(WepSphereMqQueuePusher.java:63) [messaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:58) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.12.Final.jar:5.1.12.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
```

It appears that if the ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException occurs, the transaction is marked as rollbackonly. So I tried to say the transaction to not rollback for this exception (via the annotation), but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea why it's not working ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably this problem happens because `getNewMessages` invokes some method that is transactional and transaction manager's property `globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure` is set to `true` (which is the default).

Here's the relevant piece of [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTransactionManager.html):

```
 Set whether to globally mark an existing transaction as rollback-only
 after a participating transaction failed.
 <p>Default is "true": If a participating transaction (e.g. with
 PROPAGATION_REQUIRES or PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS encountering an existing
 transaction) fails, the transaction will be globally marked as rollback-only.
 The only possible outcome of such a transaction is a rollback: The
 transaction originator <i>cannot</i> make the transaction commit anymore.
 <p>Switch this to "false" to let the transaction originator make the rollback
 decision. If a participating transaction fails with an exception, the caller
 can still decide to continue with a different path within the transaction.
 However, note that this will only work as long as all participating resources
 are capable of continuing towards a transaction commit even after a data access
 failure: This is generally not the case for a Hibernate Session, for example;
 neither is it for a sequence of JDBC insert/update/delete operations.
```

You have set `noRollbackFor` on the *outer* transaction but

1. `getNewMessages` never throws `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`
2. more importantly the transaction is marked as rollbackOnly when some other method (I guess `deleteGpsDataToSend` is annotated with `@Transactional`) throws that exception.